# Is it possible to create stack class that take any type of variable? not only 1 type

Tags: c++, stack

I have seen stack class that uses the template to define the type of data the stack hold. What if I want a stack that hold different type of data? I have a little thought into it and come close to using void pointer (but void pointer can't be dereferenced, so it is not the correct solution) So... Is it possible to have such a class?

Comment: It really sounds like you're trying to do something you shouldn't be doing... What is the context? Why can't you use a common base class or virtual and dynamic_cast<> -- or, as a last resort, use union or unsafe casting of (void *) for everything? (I assume you have full control over what will be stored in the stack<>.)

Answer (score 2):

You could have a stack of [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/any.html) values.

Answer (score 1):

There are various options, listed here from the safest to the most difficult to manage

- A common base class
- `boost::variant` (assuming you know all types beforehand)
- `boost::any` (very difficult to act on, since anything can be in there...)
- `void*` (very difficult once more and there is a memory management issue)

Pick up the one you wish.

Answer (score 0):

void pointers can't be dereferenced, sure, but you can still cast the void pointer to the actual type of pointer you need, and then dereference it.

```
  void *ptr = malloc(10);

  *ptr = 10; // won't work

  *((int *)ptr) = 10; // will work
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at C++ templates. This way you can design classes or functions to work on any data type.